# preg_replace - How to remove contents inside a tag?

Tags: php, preg-replace

Say I have this.

```
$string = "<div class=\"name\">anyting</div>1234<div class=\"name\">anyting</div>abcd"; 
$regex = "#([<]div)(.*)([<]/div[>])#";
echo preg_replace($regex,'',$string);
```

The output is
abcd

But I want 
1234abcd

How do I do it?

Comment: you just need  `preg_replace('%<div.*?</div>%i', '', $string);`

Answer (score 12):

Like this:

```
preg_replace('/(<div[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/div>)/i', '$1$3', $string);
```

If you want to remove the divs too:

```
preg_replace('/<div[^>]*>.*?<\/div>/i', '', $string);
```

To replace only the content in the divs with class name and not other classes:

```
preg_replace('/(<div.*?class="name"[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/div>)/i', '$1$3', $string);
```

Comment: That's one effective solution and quite clean. Thanks.

Comment: However, it's probably not a good idea to match html other than very specific formatted sub-sets which don't have nesting tags, ofcourse. ;) --- thought I'd just add that disclaimer seeing as I neglected to put it here when I originally posted it

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = "<div class=\"name\">anything</div>1234<div class=\"name\">anything</div>abcd"; 
echo preg_replace('%<div.*?</div>%i', '', $string); // echo's 1234abcd
```

Live example:

http://codepad.org/1XEC33sc

Answer (score 0):

add `?`, it will find FIRST occurence

```
preg_replace('~<div .*?>(.*?)</div>~','', $string);
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/c201b/3

Comment: I don't understand why do you have to create a `(.*?)` inside the div.

Comment: @Tuga: Because you do not understand, it's not reason for downvote. Because there could be <div lclasdlkasldklasdk>something</div>

Comment: I understand it perfectly and it makes no sense.

Comment: Actually this is very poor RegEx. It will not match <div> tags with no attributes (because of the space character). The ".*?" part inside the tag is indeed incorrect. If you wanted to match tags with and without attributes, then the RE should be "<div[^>]*>". Besides Tuga seems to ask about the second "(.*?)" part, which does not need to catch the div contents into buffer. It could be just ".*?". Other than that the whole expression wont match <DIV> because it's case sensitive. Add "i" after the last tilde to make it case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a simple example, but if you have a more complex one, use an HTML/XML parser. For example with [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($string);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//body/text()";
$nodes = $xpath->query($query);

$text = "";
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    $text .= $node->wholeText;
}
```

Which query you have to use or whether you have to process the DOM tree in some other way, depends on the particular content you have.